# view headers in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I can't view header in JTable while adding it into a JFrame..

```
     String[] col={"Name","ID","Marks"};
     Object[][] data={{"venkat",201,450},{"Ramesh",102,450},{"Rahul",2,430},    {"Thiman",4,434}};
     table=new JTable(data,col);
```

The above code doesn't set header in JFrame.
How to add view header in JTable while adding it into JFrame.....?

Comment: Have you read the JTable API and followed the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Tables" for working examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your table to a scroll pane, or explicitly add the header where you need it

```
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(table);
```

then add the scroll pane to your gui